# WPF dealing with time consuming UI thread update

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application where a lot of time is spent updating a control on the UI(a data visualization control which causes the app to freeze when the data being added for visualization is fairly large). I cannot use a background thread and call the dispatcher because the data that is being added to the visualizer has to be owned by the UI thread(i.e., datapoints in the visualizer). And I dont like that the UI freezes for so long. What are my options here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest profiling the application first to find the bottleneck. I bet this will narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's setup correctly (in the WPF way), it probably accepts some ViewModel class as a datasource. If you change values on that one by one, it might update the GUI each time, that is very expensive. Check if there's a SuspendLayout /ResumeLayout method or something. Or see what happens if you  create a new Viewmodel (or deep clone the existing one), write everything to that and then set the DataSource to it.

I don't know what control you're using, but an example from the Winforms DataGridView. There are two ways to add rows manually: call AddRow to add one row at a time, and AddRows to add a bunch of rows in one go and then write to them. AddRows is orders of magnitude faster than AddRow. Read the manual on your control.

GJ

Comment: Its a charting control from `visifire`. To plot a chart you need to add points to a series one at a time and then add the chart to the series

Comment: Ok, but do you add the datapoints to the existsing series? Or can you create a new one, set it up completely and then add it to the chart. When it's already 'in the chart' when you write, each write might trigger a UI update.

Comment: The series is added to the chart only after all the datapoints are added to the series. It isn't a part of the chart beforehand. I think the time consumption is because the chart is rendering for that long.

Comment: Ok that sounds like the correct way to do that. Did you ask Visifire support? Is there a big difference between debug and release? Often stuff can be slow in debug but work fine in release.

Comment: I've tried both debug and release. There isn't a significant difference. I've spoken to the support, they want me to use the dispatcher to speed things up slightly. I guess I was hoping for someway the chart would render like WPF does in a different thread so that the app wouldn't freeze.

Comment: Hmmm.. sounds like you reached the limits of what visifire can do. If you really need faster chart I think you may have to change the charting component. Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428425/recommendation-for-high-performance-wpf-chart